# How is Pickit 3 connected to PIC32?

Tags: pic, pickit

Using a PIC32MM0064GPM028, how is Pickit 3 supposed to connect to it? Reading page 3 of the [datasheet](https://www.mouser.se/datasheet/2/268/60001387c-1113833.pdf) I see no PGC/PGD-pins at all, and in [this document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/52116A.pdf) (PICkit™ 3 In-Circuit Debugger/Programmer Guide) it says all PIC32 are supported.

I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at Table 1.1 on page 17:

[image]

There are 3 programming ports available, just pick the ones that you want to use with the same number suffix. You can then map the pin back to the device you are using with this chart.